# Moment Generating Function for a specific set of moments - what's the distribution it follows?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

While studying a coin-toss experiment inspired by an interview question I stumbled upon a discrete random variable whose moments (after normalizing and centering to zero, that is $\mu=0,\sigma=1$.) are as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
E(X)&=&0\\
E(X^2)&=&1\\
E(X^3)&=&2\\
E(X^4)&=&9\\
E(X^5)&=&44
\end{eqnarray}
...and more generally $E(X^n)$ is the number of derangements on $n$ letters.
On computing the MGF (moment generating function) I find

$$E(e^{tX})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{E(X^n)}{n!}t^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_nt^n}{n!}$$

where $a_n$ is the number of derangements on $n$ letters.

Further with a few combinatorial techniques the MGF was found to be $$\frac{e^{-t}}{1-t}$$

My aim is to find a closed-form expression for the distribution function $f(x)$, just like $f(n)=\lambda^n\cdot e^{-\lambda}/n!$ for the Poisson distribution.

On looking up a comprehensive list of MGFs/families for known distributions I do not find this MGF above being any of them as listed under the heading "Examples" in the wiki resource https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function.

I even tried to use integration by parts in the equation

$$E(e^{tX})=\sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{tx}f(x)=\frac{e^{-t}}{1-t}\quad\text{(summed over all whole numbers x)}$$

both with $u=e^{tx},v=f(x)$ and vice-versa to no avail as the terms are widely affected by the behaviour of $f$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$. Could anyone throw light on how $f$ is to be found or approximated or point to some literature which helps find $f$ above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if you have two independent random variables $X,Y$ then for the MGF's we have $$M_{X+Y}(t) = M_X(t)M_Y(t).$$
Hence if we can recognize $\frac{e^{-t}}{1-t}$ to be a product of two known MGF's, we can conclude.

> Now if $X$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $1$ and $Y$ has a point mass distribution at $-1$ we get by the observation from above $$M_{X+Y}(t) = \frac{e^{-t}}{1-t}.$$

Comment: I could figure the $M_X$ and $M_Y$ splitting. But by the way how did you make that concealed spoiler??

Comment: Just write ">!" in front of the block you want to hide.